# Static IP address setting failed

Tags: linux, networking

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
                EVICE=eth11
                TYPE=Ethernet
                ONBOOT=no
                NM_CONTROLLED=yes
                BOOTPROTO=static
                IPADDR=192.168.1.7
                GATEWAY=192.168.1.2
                NETMASK=255.255.255.0
                DNS1=192.168.1.7
                DNS2=192.168.1.2
                DNS3=168.126.63.1
```

and after restart the network

```
    eth11     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:E4:AD:EB  
         inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee4:adeb/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:561 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:117996 (115.2 KiB)  TX bytes:73410 (71.6 KiB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:5384 (5.2 KiB)  TX bytes:5384 (5.2 KiB)
```

`eth11` does not configure the static IP. Any idea?

Comment: try `NM_CONTROLLED=no` and `ONBOOT=yes`

Comment: Does the first line of that file actually say `EVICE=eth11`, or is it just a copy-paste error?

Comment: I check the device with   ip link and it shows eth11

Comment: steve onboot = yes solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the onboot value to **yes**, indicating this device should be activated as boot time.

```
onboot=no
```

to

```
onboot=yes
```

This device should be activated at boot-time

Comment: somehow after i change it to static  putty does not connect to the server